# IntelliJ IDEA: is there a way to automatically format Javascript object literals?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea

I'm looking for a way to automatically format Javascript object literals in IntelliJ IDEA. I checked Settings > Code style > Javascript but couldn't find anything like this there.

Let me give an example of what I want. I want this:

```
var a = { prop1: 'abc', prop2: 'def'
         , prop3: 'ghi' };
```

to be automatically formatted like so:

```
var a = {
    prop1: 'abc',
    prop2: 'def',
    prop3: 'ghi'
}
```

I'm using IDEA 12.0.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [related feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-6375), star/vote to track the progress.

Comment: Thanks, just upvoted that feature request :) If nobody answers with anything more useful I will mark this as the accepted answer.